# Is there a way to sync Drobpox's cloud to a 3rd party backup service like AWS or B2?

Tags: backup, dropbox

Ive started using Dropbox's "cloud sync" feature to keep large files in the cloud and off my laptops internal drive.

My concern is that the only real place these files live is now in dropbox's cloud.

Is there a way to sync drobpox's cloud to a 3rd party backup service like AWS or B2 ?

Comment: These files are encrypted and only you (and Dropbox) have the key. You could download these files to anywhere and hope that when you tell Dropbox to delete them from its servers, that it actually does so.

Comment: Dropbox has an API available through e.g. Python, which you certainly could use to transfer files. My thought would be perhaps to create a virtual machine on AWS, attach some storage to it then run your Python script for Dropbox on that VM instance.